# Open file with new tab but [no name] is always there in vim

Tags: nerdtree, neovim

[image: Link to images]

Hello I open file in NERDTree using **t** but new files is always there. Before I use **vim** in folder. that mean when I located in ex: **app** folder, I run vim without type specific files to edit. when I open files in nerd tree, new file [No Name] is always there. is anyone know how to fix it?

this is my **init.vim**

```
" Specify a directory for plugins
call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')

Plug 'dense-analysis/ale'
Plug 'mattn/emmet-vim'
Plug 'neoclide/coc.nvim', {'branch': 'release'}
Plug 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
"Plug 'tsony-tsonev/nerdtree-git-plugin'
Plug 'Xuyuanp/nerdtree-git-plugin'
Plug 'tiagofumo/vim-nerdtree-syntax-highlight'
Plug 'ryanoasis/vim-devicons'
Plug 'airblade/vim-gitgutter'
Plug 'ctrlpvim/ctrlp.vim' " fuzzy find files
Plug 'scrooloose/nerdcommenter'
"Plug 'prettier/vim-prettier', { 'do': 'yarn install' }"
Plug 'christoomey/vim-tmux-navigator'
Plug 'sheerun/vim-polyglot'
Plug 'morhetz/gruvbox'
Plug 'rafi/awesome-vim-colorschemes'  
Plug 'vim-airline/vim-airline'
Plug 'Yggdroot/indentLine' 
Plug 'HerringtonDarkholme/yats.vim' " TS Syntax
Plug 'tomasiser/vim-code-dark'

" Initialize plugin system
call plug#end()

inoremap jk <ESC>
nmap <C-n> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>
vmap ++ <plug>NERDCommenterToggle
nmap ++ <plug>NERDCommenterToggle

set mouse=a
set number
set hidden
set cursorline
set expandtab
set autoindent
set smartindent
set shiftwidth=4
set tabstop=4
set encoding=utf8
set history=5000
set clipboard=unnamedplus

    " open NERDTree automatically
autocmd StdinReadPre * let s:std_in=1

autocmd VimEnter * NERDTree
" Open the existing NERDTree on each new tab.
autocmd BufWinEnter * silent NERDTreeMirror

" Exit Vim if NERDTree is the only window left.
autocmd BufEnter * if tabpagenr('$') == 1 && winnr('$') == 1 && exists('b:NERDTree') && b:NERDTree.isTabTree() |
    \ quit | endif

autocmd bufenter * if (winnr("$") == 1 && exists("b:NERDTree") 
      \ && b:NERDTree.isTabTree()) | q | endif

let g:NERDTreeGitStatusWithFlags = 1
"let g:WebDevIconsUnicodeDecorateFolderNodes = 1
"let g:NERDTreeGitStatusNodeColorization = 1
"let g:NERDTreeColorMapCustom = {
    "\ "Staged"    : "#0ee375",  
    "\ "Modified"  : "#d9bf91",  
    "\ "Renamed"   : "#51C9FC",  
    "\ "Untracked" : "#FCE77C",  
    "\ "Unmerged"  : "#FC51E6",  
    "\ "Dirty"     : "#FFBD61",  
    "\ "Clean"     : "#87939A",   
    "\ "Ignored"   : "#808080"   
    "\ }                         


let g:NERDTreeIgnore = ['^node_modules$']

" vim-prettier
"let g:prettier#quickfix_enabled = 0
"let g:prettier#quickfix_auto_focus = 0
" prettier command for coc
command! -nargs=0 Prettier :CocCommand prettier.formatFile
" run prettier on save
"let g:prettier#autoformat = 0
"autocmd BufWritePre *.js,*.jsx,*.mjs,*.ts,*.tsx,*.css,*.less,*.scss,*.json,*.graphql,*.md,*.vue,*.yaml,*.html PrettierAsync


" ctrlp
let g:ctrlp_user_command = ['.git/', 'git --git-dir=%s/.git ls-files -oc --exclude-standard']

" j/k will move virtual lines (lines that wrap)
noremap <silent> <expr> j (v:count == 0 ? 'gj' : 'j')
noremap <silent> <expr> k (v:count == 0 ? 'gk' : 'k')
nnoremap <C-s> :w<CR>
nnoremap <C-Q> :wq<CR>

" shift+arrow selection
nmap <S-Up> v<Up>
nmap <S-Down> v<Down>
nmap <S-Left> v<Left>
nmap <S-Right> v<Right>
vmap <S-Up> <Up>
vmap <S-Down> <Down>
vmap <S-Left> <Left>
vmap <S-Right> <Right>
imap <S-Up> <Esc>v<Up>
imap <S-Down> <Esc>v<Down>
imap <S-Left> <Esc>v<Left>
imap <S-Right> <Esc>v<Right>

vmap <C-c> y<Esc>i
vmap <C-x> d<Esc>i
map <C-v> pi
imap <C-v> <Esc>pi

set cindent
set t_Co=256
set t_ut=
colorscheme onedark

" sync open file with NERDTree
" " Check if NERDTree is open or active
function! IsNERDTreeOpen()        
  return exists("t:NERDTreeBufName") && (bufwinnr(t:NERDTreeBufName) != -1)
endfunction

" Call NERDTreeFind iff NERDTree is active, current window contains a modifiable
" file, and we're not in vimdiff
function! SyncTree()
  if &modifiable && IsNERDTreeOpen() && strlen(expand('%')) > 0 && !&diff
    NERDTreeFind
    wincmd p
  endif
endfunction

" Highlight currently open buffer in NERDTree
autocmd BufEnter * call SyncTree()

" coc config
let g:coc_global_extensions = [
  \ 'coc-snippets',
  \ 'coc-pairs',
  \ 'coc-tsserver',
  \ 'coc-eslint', 
  \ 'coc-prettier', 
  \ 'coc-json', 
  \ 'coc-python',
  \ ]
" from readme
" if hidden is not set, TextEdit might fail.
set hidden " Some servers have issues with backup files, see #649 set nobackup set nowritebackup " Better display for messages set cmdheight=2 " You will have bad experience for diagnostic messages when it's default 4000.
set updatetime=300

" don't give |ins-completion-menu| messages.
set shortmess+=c

" always show signcolumns
set signcolumn=yes

" Use tab for trigger completion with characters ahead and navigate.
" Use command ':verbose imap <tab>' to make sure tab is not mapped by other plugin.
inoremap <silent><expr> <TAB>
      \ pumvisible() ? "\<C-n>" :
      \ <SID>check_back_space() ? "\<TAB>" :
      \ coc#refresh()
inoremap <expr><S-TAB> pumvisible() ? "\<C-p>" : "\<C-h>"

function! s:check_back_space() abort
  let col = col('.') - 1
  return !col || getline('.')[col - 1]  =~# '\s'
endfunction

" Use <c-space> to trigger completion.
inoremap <silent><expr> <c-space> coc#refresh()

" Use <cr> to confirm completion, `<C-g>u` means break undo chain at current position.
" Coc only does snippet and additional edit on confirm.
inoremap <expr> <cr> pumvisible() ? "\<C-y>" : "\<C-g>u\<CR>"
" Or use `complete_info` if your vim support it, like:
" inoremap <expr> <cr> complete_nfo()["selected"] != "-1" ? "\<C-y>" : "\<C-g>u\<CR>"

" Use `[g` and `]g` to navigate diagnostics
nmap <silent> [g <Plug>(coc-diagnostic-prev)
nmap <silent> ]g <Plug>(coc-diagnostic-next)

" Remap keys for gotos
nmap <silent> gd <Plug>(coc-definition)
nmap <silent> gy <Plug>(coc-type-definition)
nmap <silent> gr <Plug>(coc-references)

" Use K to show documentation in preview window
nnoremap <silent> K :call <SID>show_documentation()<CR>

function! s:show_documentation()
  if (index(['vim','help'], &filetype) >= 0)
    execute 'h '.expand('<cword>')
  else
    call CocAction('doHover')
  endif
endfunction

" Highlight symbol under cursor on CursorHold
autocmd CursorHold * silent call CocActionAsync('highlight')

" Remap for rename current word
nmap <F2> <Plug>(coc-rename)

" Remap for format selected region
xmap <leader>f  <Plug>(coc-format-selected)
nmap <leader>f  <Plug>(coc-format-selected)

augroup mygroup
  autocmd!
  " Setup formatexpr specified filetype(s).
  autocmd FileType typescript,json setl formatexpr=CocAction('formatSelected')
" Update signature help on jump placeholder
  autocmd User CocJumpPlaceholder call CocActionAsync('showSignatureHelp')
augroup end

" Remap for do codeAction of selected region, ex: `<leader>aap` for current paragraph
xmap <leader>a  <Plug>(coc-codeaction-selected)
nmap <leader>a  <Plug>(coc-codeaction-selected)

" Remap for do codeAction of current line
nmap <leader>ac  <Plug>(coc-codeaction)
" Fix autofix problem of current line
nmap <leader>qf  <Plug>(coc-fix-current)

" Create mappings for function text object, requires document symbols feature of languageserver.
xmap if <Plug>(coc-funcobj-i)
xmap af <Plug>(coc-funcobj-a)
omap if <Plug>(coc-funcobj-i)
omap af <Plug>(coc-funcobj-a)

" Use <C-d> for select selections ranges, needs server support, like: coc-tsserver, coc-python
nmap <silent> <C-d> <Plug>(coc-range-select)
xmap <silent> <C-d> <Plug>(coc-range-select)

" Use `:Format` to format current buffer
command! -nargs=0 Format :call CocAction('format')

" Use `:Fold` to fold current buffer
command! -nargs=? Fold :call     CocAction('fold', <f-args>)

" use `:OR` for organize import of current buffer
command! -nargs=0 OR   :call     CocAction('runCommand', 'editor.action.organizeImport')

" Add status line support, for integration with other plugin, checkout `:h coc-status`
set statusline^=%{coc#status()}%{get(b:,'coc_current_function','')}

" Using CocList
" Show all diagnostics
nnoremap <silent> <space>a  :<C-u>CocList diagnostics<cr>
" Manage extensions
nnoremap <silent> <space>e  :<C-u>CocList extensions<cr>
" Show commands
nnoremap <silent> <space>c  :<C-u>CocList commands<cr>
" Find symbol of current document
nnoremap <silent> <space>o  :<C-u>CocList outline<cr>
" Search workspace symbols
nnoremap <silent> <space>s  :<C-u>CocList -I symbols<cr>
" Do default action for next item.
nnoremap <silent> <space>j  :<C-u>CocNext<CR>
" Do default action for previous item.
nnoremap <silent> <space>k  :<C-u>CocPrev<CR>
" Resume latest coc list
nnoremap <silent> <space>p  :<C-u>CocListResume<CR>i

set laststatus=2
let g:airline#extensions#tabline#enabled = 1
let g:airline_powerline_fonts = 1
let g:airline_statusline_ontop=0
let g:airline_theme='onedark'

let g:airline#extensions#tabline#formatter = 'default'
" navega√ß√£o entre os buffers
nnoremap <M-Right> :bn<cr>
nnoremap <M-Left> :bp<cr>
nnoremap <c-x> :bp \|bd #<cr>

let g:ale_completion_enabled = 0
let g:ale_linters = {'python': ['flake8', 'pylint'], 'javascript': ['eslint']}
```

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix it, navigate to the tab which has `[No Name]` open in it, and close that tab

```
ESC gt :tabclose
```

#### Why?

When you start Vim, Vim opens a buffer as a window in a tab. When you use NerdTree to open a new file — using `t` — in a new tab, …you're opening a new buffer as a new window in a new tab. The old one is still there. If you look at the *top left* of your Vim window  it shows two tabs open.

[image: Coinc's Vim View]

Now the confusing thing about Vim is that [Vim Tabs don't work like IDE tabs](https://joshldavis.com/2014/04/05/vim-tab-madness-buffers-vs-tabs/). In Vim, tabs are more layouts. Using them as buffers is counterintuitive. I would suggest investing some time in understanding buffers.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't ideal, but for the very first file, open it with "o" instead of "t" , this will replace the buffer instead